# How do I tell, in TypeScript, if an interface is null or otherwise not implemented?

Tags: typescript, interface, null

I have the following code:

```
 @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  onDrop(event: DragEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    const textData: string = event.dataTransfer.getData('text').replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.inputElement.focus();
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, textData);
  }
}
```

TSLint is telling me that in the call to `event.dataTransfer`, `event` is possibly null.  Okay, fair enough.

How do I tell if `event` is null in code so I can put a guard around the code?

More specifically, how do I tell if an interface is null or otherwise not implemented?

**UPDATE**:

Here's the exact photo of what the linter is telling me:

[image]

Comment: Gotta keep the linter happy......

Comment: event can't possibly be null at that point, otherwise the previous line would have thrown an error. What exactly is tslint telling you?

Comment: Added a picture of what TSLint is telling me.

Comment: That's a TS compile error, `dataTransfer` could be `null` so `getData()` is possibly an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a TS compile error, `dataTransfer` could be `null` so `getData()` is possibly an error. You should check if `dataTransfer` is not null first:

```
if (event.dataTransfer) {
    event.dataTransfer.getData('text').replace(/\D/g, '');
}
```

Comment: Duh.  Should have seen that right away.  Thank you.